# How to paint a circle with a random size on a random coordinate such that the circle is fully visible?

Tags: java, swing, random, paintcomponent

Code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
JPanel mainPanel;

int randomSize = 0; 
int randomPositionX = 0;
int randomPositionY = 0;

final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
final static int FRAME_WIDTH  = 500;

final static int TITLE_BAR    = 30 ;

final static int MAX_SIZE     = 100;
final static int MIN_SIZE     = 10 ;

/* All the below code is put into a method */

mainPanel = new JPanel(){   
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(randomPositionY, randomPositionX, randomSize, randomSize);
    }
};

do{
    randomSize = rand.nextInt(MAX_SIZE) + 1;
}while(randomSize < MIN_SIZE);

do{
    randomPositionX = rand.nextInt(FRAME_WIDTH);
    randomPositionY = rand.nextInt(FRAME_HEIGHT);
}while((randomPositionX + randomSize > FRAME_WIDTH) || (randomPositionY + randomSize > FRAME_HEIGHT - TITLE_BAR));

repaint();
```

What I want is the circle to have a random size such that it should have a minimum size of 10 and a maximum size of 100. The circle should also be painted in a random coordinate such that the circle is **fully visible** inside the JPanel `mainPanel`.

Note that `mainPanel` will be added to a JFrame whose size is set using `setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);`.

But the problem is that sometimes, a part of the circle is half outside and half inside the JPanel:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're trying to use the frame size when calculating the position of the circle, when the frame includes a variable high title bar AND frame insets
2. You're trying to use the frame size when it's irrelevant, it's the component's size you should be using, as it's within the `mainPanel`'s coordinate context which you want to paint

> So, how do I fix the issues?

Discard ALL the frame "padding"/"offsets".  The `mainPanel` has it's own coordinate context (it's top left corner will be `0x0`) and it will be within it's parent's coordinate context, so you  don't need to care about the frame or it's insets.

Simplify your calculations, for example...

```
int randomSize = MIN_SIZE + (rand.nextInt(MAX_SIZE) + 1);

int randomPositionX = rand.nextInt(getWidth() - randomSize);
int randomPositionY = rand.nextInt(getHeight() - randomSize);
```

Should allow you to produce results which won't fall outside of the viewable area, as the maximum range of the dimensions is the current size of the container minus the desired size, just beware, if the available size is smaller then `MAX_SIZE`, you will have issues ;)

The example generates a new circle every second

[image: Random Circles]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public final static int MAX_SIZE = 100;
        public final static int MIN_SIZE = 10;
        private Rectangle bounds;
        private Random rand;

        public TestPane() {
            rand = new Random();
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    int randomSize = MIN_SIZE + (rand.nextInt(MAX_SIZE) + 1);

                    int randomPositionX = rand.nextInt(getWidth() - randomSize);
                    int randomPositionY = rand.nextInt(getHeight() - randomSize);

                    bounds = new Rectangle(randomPositionX, randomPositionY, randomSize, randomSize);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (bounds != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2d.fillOval(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: So, how do I fix the issues?

Comment: @CoolGuy Discard ALL the frame references and focus on the actual size of the component